# Change color of the last point in a graph

Tags: vba, excel

---

I created a graph in VBA

But i want to the last point i have done is in another color (red)

here is my code :

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'

    i = Range("G3").Select

    j = Range("D3").Select

     With ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
            i.MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(250, 250, 250)
            j.MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(250, 250, 250)
    End With
End Sub
```

In i is the X abscisse and j is the Y abscisse of the last point !

thank you for any advice

Comment: Couldn't you use a dummy series which highlights the last point on the chart.  This link will give you a starting point - it highlights the max and min values in a chart.  Just adapt it to show the last point.  http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/FormatMinMax.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will set the last marker on the chart to red.  Note the the RGB value for red is (255, 0, 0)

```
Sub SetLastMarkerRed()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim sc As SeriesCollection
    Dim s As Series
    Dim p As Point

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set ch = ws.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Set sc = ch.SeriesCollection
    Set s = sc.Item(1)
    Set p = s.Points(s.Points.Count)
    p.MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    p.MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set ch = Nothing
    Set sc = Nothing
    Set s = Nothing
    Set p = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: TY it work well expet that it mark the first point ! the last is in the begin of the column in D3 and G3

Comment: I suppose that is a function of default sort order of the plotted data.  You can alter the point that gets modified by using a different index in this line of code: `Set p = s.Points(s.Points.Count)`  For instance, to alter the first data point, change that line to `Set p = s.Points(1)`

Comment: It still doesn't work, i did that too but it still the first point that is marked in red

Comment: This solution does work. I just checked it and included a screen-cast for your to verify it. Yet, you should note that it might be that you `Switch Row/Column` in the `Data Source`. In that case it will not be the last point but rather the last Serie in `SeriesCollection`. Then you'll have to adapt your code to `Set s = sc.Item(sc.Count)` (because your data source is inversed / upside-down).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works but it does this :

[image]

Comment: The probleme is that all other point are hidding the red point !! How can i solve this ?