# Color last point of a chart

Tags: vba, excel

### Good morning !

I want to colour the last point of my graph in red so I have this code :

```
Sub SetLastMarkerRed()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim sc As SeriesCollection
    Dim s As Series
    Dim p As Point

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set ch = ws.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Set sc = ch.SeriesCollection
    Set s = sc.Item(1)
    Set p = s.Points(s.Points.Count)
    p.MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    p.MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set ch = Nothing
    Set sc = Nothing
    Set s = Nothing
    Set p = Nothing

End Sub
```

But it color the first point, even if i remplace by

```
Set p = s.Points(1)
```

Ty for all advices :)

Comment: Isn't this question an exact copy of your last post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122441/change-color-of-the-last-point-in-a-graph?

Comment: It work well but now its another probleme, I don't know why VBA dont see the last point but the first ?

Comment: It is still an **exact** copy of the same question you asked one day ago. So, even if you are not happy with the answer provided, I am kindly asking you not to swamp this site with the same question over and over again. If you are trying to get more attention then you might want to try any of the following: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/326794 But please refrain from posting the same question more than once.

Comment: Ok Ralph I take note of what you said, sorry, should i delete my question here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color of the last point in a graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122441/change-color-of-the-last-point-in-a-graph)